# Splus: excel data conversion to form c( ), a set of concatenated data

Tags: concatenation, data-import, s-plus

I am new to Splus. I have excel data (with 1 column, 100+ rows). Could someone explain how best to import/convert this excel column data into Splus, to form c(), a set of concatenated data, e.g. c(12321, 23243, 34343, etc.) Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you considered learning R instead?

Comment: Hi. Yes, we are using R as well but in my course it's in the process of conversion - so some things we need to learn in S+. I will look into R though for similar procedures.